# bootstrap Popover close button is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use `popover` but the problem is the close button is not working inside of `data-content`, I already tried to put it in `title` and it worked fine but I really need to put it in `data-content` :)

thanks you all...

```js
$(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
        
});
```

```css
.btn {
  margin:80px
}

body {
  background: #f5f5f5
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button class="btn btn-success btn-edit"
                                                            data-toggle="popover"
                                                            data-html='true' data-placement="bottom"
                                                            data-content='<button type="button" id="close" class="close" onclick="$(&quot;.btn-edit&quot;).popover(&quot;hide&quot;);">&times;</button>'>
                                                        CLICK ME
                                                    </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML entities (`&quot;`) do not get parsed inside JavaScript expressions and that's what you have inside `onlick` attribute. But you can use backtick instead of single quote. i.e:

```
<button data-content='<button onclick="$(`.btn-edit`).popover(`hide`);">...</button>'>
```

```js
$(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
        
});
```

```css
.btn {
  margin:80px
}

body {
  background: #f5f5f5
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button class="btn btn-success btn-edit"
                                                            data-toggle="popover"
                                                            data-html='true' data-placement="bottom"
                                                            data-content='<button type="button" id="close" class="close" onclick="$(`.btn-edit`).popover(`hide`);">&times;</button>'>
                                                        CLICK ME
                                                    </button>
```